# Help me use python-bitcoinrpc

Tags: json-rpc, python

I have got the api working and i can run commands like

```
access = AuthServiceProxy("http://root:123@127.0.0.1:8332")
access.getinfo()
```

However not sure how to use more complicated commands such as:
move "fromaccount" "toaccount" amount ( minconf "comment" )

Tried something like this, but i get a syntax error in python.

```
name = "bob"
name2 = "sam"
balance = 0.0001
access.move(name name2 balance)
```

Doing it like this i get JSONRPCException:

```
name = "bob"
name2 = "sam"
balance = 0.0001
access.move('%s' '%s' '%s'), (name, name2, balance)
```

Any help appreciated.

Comment: Do `bob` and `sam` represent `accounts` in your bitcoin-core wallet?

Comment: yes, those accounts exist.

Comment: try this one: `acess.move(name, name2, balance)`, Sam and Bob should be bitcoin address.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
access.move(name, name2, balance)
```

Answer (score 1):

Steps to transfer bitcoin from Sam to Bob:

Create a python script to connect to Sam's RPC server. Suppose Sam's IP is 172.28.128.4

```
from jsonrpc import ServiceProxy
access = ServiceProxy("http://user:password@172.28.128.4:8332")
print(access.sendtoaddress(Bob's_Bitcoin_Address, Transfer_Balance))
```

Comment: I have an environmental variable called `BTCRPCURL` which allows `ServiceProxy(os.environ.get("BTCRCURL"))`